# What are the beginning and closing template of a video?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I often see a beginning and a closing attached to a video, especially videos produced by some big brands, and such beginning and closing are the same for the same brand. It's like a template: the main content is surrounded by two clips.

For instance, [this clip](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxT1rdo07KhAVgVhXMXCDxAd9NqyLyS0Lm) is the beginning, and [this is](https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkxw3869SUR9imvwUeoYkLKZeD4vVh2znL-) the closing of [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9qGmO8Yy-Y) by Stanford. These two happen to be the same, but in some videos they are different, especially for lecture videos on Coursera(due to the paywall I will not cite).

What can I call them as a native English speaker? In Chinese they are 片头 and 片尾, and I don't think "beginning" and "closing" seem like a good fit.

Comment: Pardon the late addition; I don't think this is quite the best answer for the example, but "intro" and "outro" are closely related.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK we'd probably call this an **[ident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station_identification)** ("EYE-dent") or **station ID**. Idents often contain a logo and they're usually accompanied by a brief melodic figure or fanfare.

A **[production logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_logo)** is generally more extravagent and uses sound and either animation (like RKO's "transmitter") or film footage (like MGM's "Leo the Lion").

Answer (score 0):

The start of a video is usually called a [**"title sequence"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_sequence):

> A title sequence (also called an opening sequence or intro) is the method by which films or television programmes present their title and key production and cast members, utilizing conceptual visuals and sound (often a opening theme song with visuals, akin to a brief music video).

The end of a video is usually called a [**"closing credits"/"end credits"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_credits):

> Closing credits or end credits are a list of the cast and crew of a particular motion picture, television program, or video game.

Comment: Why "title sequence"? There is no title.

Comment: @LernerZhang look at the meaning of it - **... presenting their title ...**

Comment: in video terminology "titles" are any words that are written to the screen.  Hence "subtitles" are words that are written at the bottom of the screen.